# Dropdown menu and animations

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML5 and CSS3.
I am trying to have dropdown menu with linear animation.
I have already copied the animation from an existing template and the last remaining thing for me is to show the dropdown menu items. What is my fault in the given CSS3?

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" charset="utf-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>My Page Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>

                <ul class="menu" id="nav">
                    <li><a href=""><span>
                    Tab5</span></a>
                        <ul class="menu-hover">
                            <li><a href="">Tab5_1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Tab5_2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Tab5_3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href=""><span>
                    Tab4
                    </span></a>
                        <ul class="menu-hover">
                            <li><a href="">Tab4_1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Tab4_2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="candidates.html"><span>Tab3</span></a>
                        <ul class="menu-hover">
                            <li><a href="">Tab3_1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Tab3_2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Tab3_3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Tab3_4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href=""><span>
                    Tab2
                    </span></a>
                        <ul class="menu-hover">
                            <li><a href="">Tab2_1</a></li>
                            <li><a href=""> Tab2_2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Tab2_3 </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>


                    <li><a href="vision.html"><span>Tab1 </span></a>
                        <ul class="menu-hover">
                            <li><a href="">Tab1_1 </a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Tab1_2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Tab1_3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
              </ul>
        </div>              

        <div><footer id="footer"></footer></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS3 File:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
body {
    background:#f4f4f4;
}

#nav {
    width:933px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:250px;
    padding-top:20px;
}

ul li {
    background:#2a2a2a;
    list-style: none;
    height: 44px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px 5px;
}
ul li a {
    width: 175px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 53px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #636393;
    padding:0px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
     -webkit-transition: .2s all linear;
     -moz-transition: .2s all linear;
     -o-transition: .2s all linear;
     transition: .2s all linear;
}

ul li a:visited {
color:#fff;
}


ul li:nth-child(1) a , #myID li:nth-child(1) a, #myID li:nth-child(2) a , #myID li:nth-child(3) a
{
border-color: #636393;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) a {
border-color: #B5222D;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) a {
border-color: #D4953C;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) a {
border-color: #609491;
}
ul li:nth-child(5) a {
border-color: #87A248;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #636393;
 height: 9px;
 color: #fff;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #B5222D;
 height: 9px;
 color: #fff;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #D4953C;
 height: 9px;
 color: #fff;
}

ul li:nth-child(4) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #609491;
 height: 9px;
 color: #fff;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #87A248;
 height: 9px;
 color: #fff;
}

ul.menu-hover{
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top:100%;
opacity: 0;
height: 0;
width: 150px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #636393;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:hover .menu-hover{
visibility: visible;
height: 40px;
opacity: 1;
}

ul.menu-hover li{
height: 100%;
border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
background-color: #2a2a2a;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;

}

ul.menu-hover li:hover{
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2a2a2a, #434343);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#2a2a2a, #434343);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#2a2a2a, #434343);
background-image: linear-gradient(#2a2a2a, #434343);
box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally corrected my CSS3 file to be as follows:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
body {
    background:#f4f4f4;
}

#nav {
    width:933px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:250px;
    padding-top:20px;
}

#nav li {
    background:#2a2a2a;
    list-style: none;
    height: 44px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px 5px;
}
#nav li a {
    width: 175px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 53px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #636393;
    padding:0px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
     -webkit-transition: .2s all linear;
     -moz-transition: .2s all linear;
     -o-transition: .2s all linear;
     transition: .2s all linear;
}

#nav li a:visited {
color:#fff;
}


#nav li:nth-child(1) a , #myID li:nth-child(1) a, #myID li:nth-child(2) a , #myID li:nth-child(3) a
{
border-color: #636393;
}

#nav li:nth-child(2) a {
border-color: #B5222D;
}
#nav li:nth-child(3) a {
border-color: #D4953C;
}
#nav li:nth-child(4) a {
border-color: #609491;
}
#nav li:nth-child(5) a {
border-color: #87A248;
}

#nav li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #636393;
 height: 9px;
 color: #fff;
}

#nav li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #B5222D;
 height: 9px;
 color: #fff;
}
#nav li:nth-child(3) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #D4953C;
 height: 9px;
 color: #fff;
}

#nav li:nth-child(4) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #609491;
 height: 9px;
 color: #fff;
}

#nav li:nth-child(5) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #87A248;
 height: 9px;
 color: #fff;
}



.menu li{
list-style: none;
float: left;
position: relative;
height: 40px;
}

.menu>li{
background-color: #a82222;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#a82222, #670000);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#a82222, #670000);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#a82222, #670000);
background-image: linear-gradient(#a82222, #670000);
border-left: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
border-right: 1px solid #7e0000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
}

.menu li:first-child{
border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
border-left: none;
}

 .menu li:last-child{
border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
 border-right: none;
 }

.menu a{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 0 20px;
font-family: 'Verdana', arial;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 40px;
}

.menu li:hover{
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #470000;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #470000;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #470000;
background-color: #a82222;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#911212, #670000);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#911212, #670000);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#911212, #670000);
background-image: linear-gradient(#911212, #670000);
}

.menu li:hover span:after{
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
}

ul.menu-hover{
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top:100%;
opacity: 0;
height: 0;
width: 150px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:hover .menu-hover{
visibility: visible;
height: 100%;
opacity: 1;
}

.menu-hover li{
height: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #696969;
background-color: #2a2a2a;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
}

.menu-hover li:hover{
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2a2a2a, #434343);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#2a2a2a, #434343);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#2a2a2a, #434343);
background-image: linear-gradient(#2a2a2a, #434343);
box-shadow: none;
}

.menu-hover a{
color: white;
}

.menu a span:after{
content: "";
border-left: 3px solid transparent;
border-right: 3px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 3px solid white;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
right: 35px;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
}

.menu-hover li:first-child, .menu-hover li:last-child{
border-radius: 0;
}

.menu a:after {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.07);
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.menu ul ul { position: absolute; }
```

it looks like you only have it on hover. You don't need to put it on hover.

oh sorry

also try this one FIRST

```
ul .menu-hover { position: absolute; }
```

in your code you have ul.menu-hover, there needs to be a space between them

Comment: execuse me where do I use .menu.menu-hover? I did not do that

Comment: sorry ul.menu-hover but it might work better doing .menu .menu-hover, i edited my post

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have tried your three suggestions but it did not work